# Can't enable CORS in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cors

**NOTICE:** This works in **Firefox** but in **Chrome** not working. Why? What I miss?

When I try to run edit function in form it should get data via AngularJS.

```
var i;
var url = window.location.href;
var param = url.split("?");
    param = param[param.length - 1];

var jsonUrl = "http://api.hiremein.rs/?" + param;

$(".update-book").click(function(){
    i = $( this ).data('key');
});
var rest = angular.module('rest', []);
rest.controller('restCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $(".update-book").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $http.get(jsonUrl, function(req, res){
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "X-Requested-With");
            res.send(
                {jsonUrl}
            );
        })
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.data[i]; 
            });
        }, 300); 
    });
});
```

When code is executed I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.hiremein.rs/?page=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://client.hiremein.rs' is therefore not allowed access.

I also tried to add

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

to `index.php` on **client** and also on **API** side.

But error is not gone away.

Comment: have you tried just the domain in the server-side? CORS can do *, null or the domain (hiremein.rs)

Comment: as in res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://api.hiremein.rs/');

Comment: Tried to do that, In Firefox is working but in Chrome still not working. There must be way to do that in Chrome.

Comment: You can't set CORS headers in the client (well, you can but they do anything useful).  They can only be set on your server to enable CORS.  It is the server that decides who can access it from a browser.  And, if you put certain custom headers on the request, then you also need your server to support preflighting with the OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assumed, probably wrongly, that the code shown was server side code - on reflection, it looks like client side code - in which case the following is irrelevant

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "X-Requested-With");
```

well, that looks 7 kinds of wrong wrong ... I'm sure `X-Requested-With` is not a host - perhaps you meant

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

Of course, if you have non-standard headers, you'll possibly need to handle [preflighting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)